# Python Pandas - Splitting a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to split a column from a CSV file. The first column contains a date (YYmmdd) and then time (HHmmss) so the string looks like 20221001131245. I want to split this so it reads 2022 10 01 in one column and then 13:12:45 in another.

I have tried the str.split but I recognise my data isn't in a string so this isn't working.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
 
CSVPath = "/Desktop/Test Data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(CSVPath)
 
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) combined with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
# convert to datetime
s = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
# or if integer as input
# s = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# format strings
df['date'] = s.dt.strftime('%Y %m %d')
df['time'] = s.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
              col        date      time
0  20221001131245  2022 10 01  13:12:45
```

##### alternative

using string slicing and concatenation

```
s = df['col'].str
df['date'] = s[:4]+' '+s[4:6]+' '+s[6:8]
df['time'] = s[8:10]+':'+s[10:12]+':'+s[12:]
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you. I guess my next question would be manipulating the columns and how to have the Date Time columns displayed first and also how to hide other columns from the CSV.

Comment: If you want to drop the original column you can use `pop` in the first step: `s = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('col'), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`. To insert your new columns in a specific location see [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question from your comment:

You can use `df.drop(['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2'], axis=1)` to drop unwanted columns.

I am guessing you want to write the data back to a .csv file? Use the following snippet to only write specific columns:

```
df[['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2']].to_csv("/Desktop/Test Data Edited.csv")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).